# python can not get search and replace to substitute data

Tags: python, regex, replace

I have tried 30-40 combinations of re.sub, sub(), str.replace(),using generators, assigning variables, using the write function, etc. I have been able to get python to write the "data" to a new file but have not been able to get it to write the "new" data to either a new file or using rb+ on the open "tar" file . Please see code below:

```
modcwd = os.getcwd() #assign var to modman DIR
patch = 'hex.patch' #hardcode patch to var
tar = 'Hex!.exe' #hardcode patch to var
alphex = 'h' #hardcode patch to var
patlst = [line.strip() for line in open(patch,'rb',1)] #Read Patch start
if alphex == 'h' :
     old = patlst[patlst.index('OLD:')+1] #get old data str
     new = patlst[patlst.index('NEW:')+1] #get new data str
     old = old.lower();old = ''.join(old.split())
     new = new.lower();new = ''.join(new.split())
pircwd = os.chdir('..'); pircwd = os.getcwd() ##DIR change
with open(tar,'rb') as f:
    data = binascii.hexlify(f.read(160))
if old in data:
    print 'found!'
    print 'old:',old;print 'new:',new;print'data:',data
    #put search and replace code here!
else:
    print 'not found'
```

This is the current output printed in the Komodo debugger:

```
found!
old: 69732070726f6772616d2063616e6e6f742062652072756e20696e20444f5320
new: 69732070726f6772616d2063616e2020202062652072756e20696e20444f5320
data: 4d5a90000300000004000000ffff0000b800000000000000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000400100000e1fba0e00b409cd21b8014ccd21546869732070726f6772616d2063616e6e6f742062652072756e20696e20444f53206d6f64652e0d0d0a2400000000000000b9ee3e99fd8f50cafd8f50cafd8f50ca3e800fcafc8f50caee870fcaf18f50ca
```

The "old" and "new" are from the hex.patch file and the "data" is the first 160 bytes from the "tar" exe file. The comment #put search and replace code here! is the area where I had tried all the variations.

Comment: I am not enjoying your semicolons.

Comment: Show what you're actually trying.

Comment: You can't write to the tar file because it's already closed by the context manager by the time you get inside your if statement. Indent that and you should be good to go.

Comment: @Decency, thanks did not catch the indent (or lack of) was closing it out. That worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `str.replace` should just work, but it is unclear where it went wrong on your end... Please try the following, it should work just fine:

```
if old in data:
    print 'found!'
    print 'old:',old
    print 'new:',new
    print 'data:',data

    #put search and replace code here!
    data = data.replace(old, new)
    print 'new data:', data
```